# MySQL dumping/restoring dump - encoding

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with copying database from production server to my home server. The text ends up garbled. The database settings are as follows (first the production server settings, then home server settings):

### Source server

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin2                     |
| character_set_connection | latin2                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin2                     |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| collation_connection     | latin2_general_ci          |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci            |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci            |
| completion_type          | NO_CHAIN                   |
| concurrent_insert        | AUTO                       |
| connect_timeout          | 10                         |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Destination server:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                          |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                          |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
| character_sets_dir       | d:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\share\charsets\ |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci                               |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci                               |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci                               |
| completion_type          | NO_CHAIN                                      |
| concurrent_insert        | AUTO                                          |
| connect_timeout          | 10                                            |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What would be the dumping/importing routine for those servers? Right now I'm dumping with --default-character-set=latin2 -> this results in correctly encoded UTF8 file. Unfortunatly when importing the file using --default-character-set=UTF8, some text is ok, while some is garbled.

Comment: Could be win/nix issue. Try dos2unix on file.

Comment: Good idea, didn't help unfortunatly. The dump file itself has correct encoding (when opening in notepad++ it has UTF-8 w/o BOM set, and the text is displaying correctly). When importing, parts of the text display correctly, and parts are garbled.